Is private static nested class not "private"?
Why am I being able to access "private" nested class outside the enclosing class (first) ?
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class hi {
    static class first {
        private static class nested {
            void main() {
                System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        first.nested a = new first.nested();
        a.main();
    }

}


@RRR: It should compile, and it compiles fine for me - what error are you seeing?

@JonSkeet I used an online fiddle and forgot to rename hi to Main. My bad.

private is for the ``outside'', enclosing is not outside...

Even if it worked the way you intuitively feel it would/should, such a construct is not very useful anyway. If you don't want to use Nested directly in Hi, then just... don't. If you really really want to enforce it for some reason, then move First to its own file.

From JLS 6.6.1:

Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private. Access is permitted only when the access occurs from within the body of the top level class or interface that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

The hi class encloses the nested class, therefore access to nested is permitted anywhere within the body of hi.
